# DatabaseObjectNotClosedException

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I've noticed that there are several question on this exception. But they do not solve my problem.

I have a databaseHelper class that has a inner class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
          OpenHelper(Context context) {
             super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
             db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
          }
          @Override
          public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
             Log.w("DBHELPER", "Upgrading database");
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

             onCreate(db);
          }


      }
```

I have a service that updates the db continuously. And a activities that fetches data from the db .

In both the service and the activities the dbHelper get created:

```
this.dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

And I do get the DatabaseObjectNotClosedException. Do I need to close the DatabaseHelper? How would I do that? Or how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that needs to be taken care of outside of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

You need to close your database connection anytime your activity or service is paused/stopped.  If you don't do this, Android will throw that exception you keep seeing in LogCat.

The best practice for this depends on whether you have a global or local DB object.

**Local**

Use a `try catch finally` block. Open your database in the try, and then close it in finally. That way no matter if there was an error or not, your database is closed.

```
OpenHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
try {
    db =  dh.getWritableDatabase();
} catch(SQLiteException e){

} finally {
    if(db != null && db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}
```

**Global**

Utilize the Android lifecycle to manage your database. Open the database in `onResume`, and close it in `onPause`.

```
OpenHelper dh = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    this.db =  dh.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
protected void onPause( {
    if(db != null && db.isOpen()){
        db.close();
    }
}
```

As for your `Service` issue.  Read up on the [Service Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle).  You can use the pattern I implemented in the *Global* section there.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I handle this in the Service. I might want to add to the db from the Service while a Activity needs to fetch.
And does Services has a onResume/onPause?

Comment: Actually I just noticed some of my code is wrong. It references a database helper, and not an actual database object.  Let me fix it.

Comment: Thanks! But I the Service is running as long as the app is active. 'AutoRefresh' service.

Comment: Your service should then use the **Local** pattern I specified.  Only have an open database when you are using it. Don't have it sitting there open when the service is just polling/waiting.